# How to obtain java.sql.Connection instance from Cassandra Cluster instance?

Tags: cassandra

In the Java code I am working on, I am handed over a Cassandra Cluster object (`com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster`). I need to obtain or build a `java.sql.Connection` object from the Cluster object. I am wondering how I can create the new instance (with minimal coding hopefully). Any pointer is appreciated.

If it helps, my code uses Dropwizard Java framework. Thanks.